# Render Partial View in Bootstrap Popover Content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my MVC View I have the following:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-content="@Html.Action("Popover","Client")">Simon Jones</a>
```

This works as I want it, loading the partial View returned by the *Popover* Action in the *Client* Controller. However, I would like it so that, with minimal effort, wherever the client's name appears in the application, this popover is added near enough automatically. Something like:

```
<a href="#" class="clientPopover">Simon Jones</a>
```

With Javascript in a separate file, linked to each page, like this:

```
$(".clientPopover").popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: '@Html.Action("Popover","Client")'
    })
```

I realise that I can't use the HTML Helper in the Javascript as I have written it here, but I have tried a multitude of different ways to accomplish this, without success.

The key requirement is that I can very easily specify that an element should have a popover attached which renders a partial view in its content. I will want to achieve the same thing with different items of data throughout the application, not just clients, so what I'm aiming for is one place to store the location of the partial views for the popovers for each item of data (e.g. client, staff, building, etc.).

**EDIT:**
I simplified my requirements to make this question easier to understand, but I realise now that this has led to an answer which works for my simplified problem but not my actual problem. It's been suggested that I could load the Popover content into a hidden element on the page and then display this in the Popover as required. However, in practice my page may have lots of different clients' names displayed at the same time (e.g. in a table), and hovering over each name would display that client's details in the Popover. I could use Ajax to update the content of my hidden element each time before populating the Popover, but I doubt that's going to be very performant, and feels over complicated.

What I was originally hoping was that once I'd figured out how to call the Action to load the Popover content for one client, I'd be able to extend the solution to also pass the id of client, so that the data for the Popover was loaded dynamically. I really thought this would be simpler than it seems to be!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the client's name with your link on server side or on client side.

On client side I would do it like this:

```
/* assume there is a main container with your content that has the class .content */ 
var html = $('.content').html();
var linkHtml = '<a href="#" class="clientPopover">Simon Jones</a>';
var newHtml = html.replace(/Simon\s+Jones/gi, linkHtml); 
$('.content').html(newHtml);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s9Laumpq/

However the smarter way is to do it on server side, because the javascript way you could break other scripts that have attached event handlers to some html elements in your code. In asp.net you would need this function to do something similar:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As for the second issue, you could write the popover-content in a javascript variable in your main html file

```
var popoverContent = '@Html.Action("Popover","Client")';
```

and use that varialbe in the separate javascript file

```
$(".clientPopover").popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: popoverContent 
});
```

Just assure that the assignment of the variable happens before the inclusion of the javascript file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the fiddle. I think the second issue is the more pressing, and the problem is that your solution doesn't work for me - if I declare the variable popoverContent as you've suggested, it doesn't get rendered in the popover content. I don't think you can use `@Html.Action` in Javascript like that. I can use `@Html.url` and that works, but it just sets the variable to a string which is the path to the View, not the actual HTML of the View.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so much into .net, but as far as i understand, the method @Html.Action returns the markup as a string directly to the output stream. So if you do this in your HTML file and write the output in the JS variable like described above it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood your question-

I've accomplished something similar by writing extensions to the HTML helper for the several different types of links that are shown in many different places on our website. So then instead of writing explicit anchor tags in my view code, I make calls like:

```
@Html.ClientLink(Model.ClientName)
```

Your HTML Helper extensions would look like:

```
public static class MvcHtmlLinkExtensions
{

    public static HtmlString ClientLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string clientName)
    {
        return new HtmlString(String.Format("<a href=\"#\" class=\"clientPopover\">{0}</a>", clientName));
    }

}
```

You'd do the same for the different types of links. Our extensions are actually more complicated in that they take an ID as additional parameter and embed it in the anchor as a data-clientID attribute, which is later pulled by the javascript and embedded in the popover URL. This allows showing custom popover data for each different client. (Similar to how Netflix.com shows movie details when you mouse over a title).

Edit:
I see from your comment on the other answer that I've misunderstood your question. I believe you're misusing the content parameter of the popover function. That parameter takes a string that is the actual HTML to be rendered in the content, and if this string is the same for every client, I believe Mario A's suggestion should work. However, if you need the content to be loaded from a partial view that is rendered on the server on demand, you'll need to use ajax:

```
content: function () {
        var output = '';
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "@Html.Action("Popover", "Client")"
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {
                output = response;
                    }
                });
            return output;
        },
```

Note- you can only use the Html.Action helpers if this function is rendered in a razor view, and not if it lives in a static js file. If the latter is the case, you'll need to hardcode the path to the action serving the HTML.

Further edit- I see now that you *are* looking to preload the contents of hte partial view. To do this, I think the cleanest way is to render your partial view in another part of that page in a hidden div,

```
<div id="popover_content" style="display:none">
    @Html.Action("Popover", "Client")
</div>
```

and then the popover script would set the popover contents to the html in that div as such:

```
content: function() {
    return $('#popover_content').html();
```

Another edit, answering revised question:
I think that a variation of my final solution would work. You can load n hidden content divs uniquely named with the id of the client, and store the client id in a data- attribute in each link. Then your popover script just finds all anchors with that attribute, and calls popover on each of them, using the value of the attribute to find the content to load.

I created a working jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/01w8pvkv/

Depending on the number of clients you plan to load on a single page, and how much content will go in each div, you may want to consider just pulling the data from Ajax.

Comment: Your final solution is a nice one for the problem as I originally presented it. However, that was actually a simplification of the real problem (as I've now explained in my edited question), made to try and make the question easier to understand. The actual problem, which will include multiple client names on the same page, probably isn't suited to the pre-loaded hidden element solution.